# count unique combinations in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count number of matches between two teams.

```
select home.home_team, home.away_team, (home_matches_against+away_matches_against) as matches
from
(select home_team, away_team, count(home_team) as home_matches_against
from results
group by home_team, away_team) as home
join
(select away_team, home_team, count(away_team) as away_matches_against
from results
group by away_team, home_team) as away
on home.home_team=away.away_team and home.away_team=away.home_team
```

output:
[image]

As you can see count of matches between tow teams are duplicated.

My desired result is for example:

```
home team  away _team  matches
England    Scotland    117
Wales      Scotland    106
```

and etc. I dont want count of matches to be duplicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE home.home_team < home.away_team;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use LEAST and GREATEST.
Something like:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM ( SELECT LEAST(home_team, away_team) AS home_team,
              GREATEST(home_team, away_team) AS away_team,
              matches
       FROM results
      ) AS t1
 GROUP BY t1.home_team, t1.away_team,t1.matches;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uLPPE1DoKjKYBoSXfKahJN/21

Comment: You forgot the COUNT part.

Comment: @jarlh this is a demonstration of how to use  LEAST and  GREATEST. With sample data would be much easier to give an proper solution